# Write a method that will remove all the occurrences of the substring “rawr”

Tags: java

noRawr(“hellorawrbye”) “hellobye”, 
noRawr(“rawrxxx”) “xxx”,
noRawr(“xxxrawr”) “xxx”, 
noRawr(“rrawrun”) “run”, 
noRawr(“rawrxxxrawrrawrawr”) “xxxawr”

```
public static String noRawr(String str) // 7
{
    String result = str;

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length() - 3; i++) {
       if (result.substring(i, i + 4).equals("rawr")) {
            result = result.substring(0, i) + result.substring(i + 4);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: We're more than happy to help you fix your code, but you need to at least try something on your own first. We won't write your assignment for you.

Comment: You'll have a much better chance of getting useful help if you actually ask a question. As @Vulcan said, we're not going to do everything for you. What have you tried that has not worked?

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time using this site. This works for “hellorawrbye”, “rawrxxx”, “xxxrawr”, "rrawrun", however not for “rawrxxxrawrrawrawr”.

Comment: `result.replaceAll("rawr", "")` Will this work? OR you have the requirement to do it by not using any inbuilt API method.

Comment: I haven't learned that yet so yes im not allowed to use inbuilt API methods

Comment: `return "";`  All occurrences of "rawr" will be gone.

Comment: I'd think the way you're doing it now won't work for multiple "rawr"s in a row because once you remove a rawr, i points to the start of the next one but you immediately increment it. So, maybe decrement i after rebuilding result?

Comment: Besides, what do you do if the input string is "rararawrwrwr"?

Comment: You're allowed to use some of the methods of the `String` class, but not others?! (`String.length()` and `String.substring()` are themselves inbuilt API methods, you know.) Also, the last example is somewhat ambiguous; it assumes 'rawr' instances will be removed from a specific direction. Were I in your class, I'd remove them from the other direction, such that the last example's output was 'xxxraw', which satisfies the requirement [of removing all instances of the substring 'rawr'].

Comment: Thanks for the help. And I will take your comment cabbagery, as constructive criticism thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that after removing "rawr" you move to next position in String ignoring fact that your String have changed and need to be checked again at the same position.

Take a look

```
>xxxrawrrawrawr
    ^we are here now and we will remove "rawr" 
     so we will get
>xxxrawrawr
    ^do we want to move to next position, or should we check again our string?
```

Try maybe this way:

```
public static String noRawr(String str) // 7
{
    String result = str;

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length() - 3; ) {// I move i++ from here
        if (result.substring(i, i + 4).equals("rawr")) {
            result = result.substring(0, i) + result.substring(i + 4);
        }else{
            i++; //and place it here, to move to next position 
                 //only if there wont be any changes in string
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] data = {"hellorawrbye","rawrxxx","xxxrawr","rrawrun","rawrxxxrawrrawrawr"};
    for (String s : data) {
        System.out.println(s+ " -> " + noRawr(s));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
hellorawrbye -> hellobye
rawrxxx -> xxx
xxxrawr -> xxx
rrawrun -> run
rawrxxxrawrrawrawr -> xxxawr
```